# Any chance of failure in REPLACE over INSERT?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table that I'm inserting records into.  It has a primary key made out of two fields.  My syntax up until now has been a simple:

`INSERT into table (`field`,`field`,`field`) VALUES ('foo', 'bar', foo')` type deal, but I've come across the scenario where I may need to overwrite existing values.

I am familiar, and in the past, have used the `INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...` syntax, but I recently came across the much more simple `REPLACE INTO...` syntax.

My assumption of this `REPLACE INTO` is that IF no data exists for the primary key I'm writing to, it will act as an INSERT.  IF the primary does exist however, it will delete the record and insert a new one.  Is this correct?

If this is correct, are there any downsides to me just forgoing the `INSERT INTO...` statement and running a `REPLACE INTO...` for 100% of the lines users are inserting into the table?  Are there any potential risks to using the `REPLACE INTO...` 100% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE does a DELETE first, so if you use foreign key constraints with ON DELETE CASCADE, you could unintentionally delete a lot of dependent data. The re-insert step of REPLACE will not recover that data deleted from dependent tables.

I think I've seen cases where REPLACE causes a new auto-increment value to be generated for the primary key. Maybe if the conflict is based on a secondary UNIQUE KEY instead of the primary key, That could throw off other references to the row even if you don't use foreign key constraints.

Comment: Great - thank you.  This table has no foreign dependencies, nor does it have any auto-increment - just a unique key so that users cannot add the same line twice - only overwrite an existing one.